Mathematica just returns the same equation when asked to solve integral equation of Volterra
I am new to Mathematica. I try to compile the example shown in this article
After copying and pasting the first two lines, and then pressing Shift + Enter, the program always returns the initial equation.

It is not returning the solution shown in the article.


Try this code DSolveValue[y[x] == x^3 + \[Lambda]  Integrate[(t - x) y[t], {t, 0, x}], y[x], x]

I use Mathematica version 13.3 and obtain the desired result immediately.  Which version are you using? Also try to start from a fresh kernal.

@MichaelWeyrauch As we can see from figure above there is a trial version has been used.

@AlexTrounev code works!

@MaroonRacoon Very good. This means that you can't just copy code from webpage.
